# What's the difference between :root and *?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When we declare variable in CSS, why we do write:

```css
:root
{
    --bgcolor:orange;
}

/* instead of */

*
{
    --bgcolor:orange;
}
```

What is the difference between both of those things?

Answer (score 1):

[`:root` is a pseudo selector that is equivalent to `html` 99% of the time, but with higher *specificity* (specificity equal to html + class)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root).

`:root` selects the root element of the document based on it's *format*. It exists as [CSS can be used in other document formats (SVG, XML)](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/root/).

`*` would apply the css to every element on the page. This is usually reserved for normalisation, fonts etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `:root` is simply a [pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) for the `<html>` element. When setting CSS custom properties/vars, they are being set on the root element - think of it like a global variable.

If you use `*` ([universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)) - it's setting the custom property/var on **EVERY** element (e.g., `div`, `p`, `span`, ect.) in the DOM.

Using `:root` is simply allowing all children elements access to that property/var without the unnecessary overhead of computing that for all elements of a DOM.

Comment: Be aware that `:root` supersedes `html` in CSS. You can simply test this by setting a different `font-size` in both. I just tested this with `32px` and `12px` respectively.

Comment: @RenevanderLende correct. It's more specific and even mentions that in the linked MDN article. The question presented by OP is _what's the difference_ between the two selectors.

Answer (score -1):

Difference between `*` and `:root`

`*` is a universal selector

`:root` is a pseudo selector

`*` Its specificity will be higher.

`:root` Its specificity will be less.